# How can I programmatically git fetch once without a password and the other times with a password?

Tags: git, github, ssh

First off, please let me know if I should rephrase my wording. I'm still learning the most effective way to word questions.

So my situation is that we have a lab setting with lots of computers with multiple users using each computer. The users are not developers, but do edit some scripts that they need to push. I have created a few helper scripts that will guide them through creating branches and switching branches. However, one feature I would really like is whenever a user wants to run said scripts, there is a check in place to make sure they are on the latest version of the branch. This needs to be run in the background so that they are not asked to enter their username/pass.

This is the check:

```
git fetch --prune
branchname=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);
changes=$(git log origin/$branchname ^HEAD);
if [[ ! -z "$changes" ]]; then
    echo "You may not have the latest version of the branch. Run git pull from ~/path/to/repo/ to bring in the latest changes"
    echo ""
fi
```

The problem is that we need to do a git fetch and we want to keep the url as HTTPS so that whenever the user does a push, they are using their own account.

If we use ssh, then it won't ask for the username/password when the user does it and the same if we use a credential helper. We also don't want to store the password in plain text.

Typing this question I realized that I can change the url for fetch to use ssh and push to use https. Is that the best solution? If so, is creating an ssh key and deploying to all the computers the best way to do this?

We are using this with Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is always tricky, but since you are using GitHub, there's a very handy always-password-free alternative, at least if the repository is public.

For your Git to call up another (foreign) Git on the Internet-phone, you can, as you already know, use `ssh://url` or `http://url` or `https://url`.  These each use a different port and protocol; `ssh` uses secure-shell, with public and private keys; `http` uses unsecured (no SSL/TLS) Web-browser-style access; and `https` uses secured (SSL/TLS) Web-browser-style access.  The last one requires a password, and the first one requires a key; but the middle one requires nothing at all.

So that's one method.  But Git also has a more-efficient `git` scheme: `git://url` means the same as `http://url`, but uses the Git port and protocol.  This is also un-authenticated, so it does not require a password.  It just needs public access, the same as `http://url`.  GitHub supports this as well.

If the repositories are not public, a stored ssh key will work.  However, if there's an ssh key that grants access, that probably also suffice for push, so I am not sure why this would be an issue in the first place.

> Typing this question I realized that I can change the url for fetch to use ssh and push to use https.

Yes, or the same with `http` or `git` as the protocol (the "scheme" part of the URL).  In fact, Git supports two separate URLs for one remote, so you can just set the remote's fetch URL (`remote.origin.url`) to the password-free version, and the remote's push URL (`remote.origin.pushurl`) to the password-based version.

That said, there's a minor flaw or two in this script:

> ```
> git fetch --prune
> branchname=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);
> ```

If `HEAD` is "detached", this will just print `HEAD`, so you will get `branchname=HEAD`.  It's probably better to do:

```
branchname=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD) || die "not on a branch"
```

(where `die` prints a message and exits)

> ```
> changes=$(git log origin/$branchname ^HEAD);
> ```

This assumes that the *upstream* for the current branch is named the same as the current branch.  That may not be the case, and in fact there may be no upstream at all.  Exactly what to do for the last case (no upstream set) is up to you but you could test:

```
git rev-parse --quiet --verify @{upstream} > /dev/null || exit
```

(this lets Git itself print `fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'` or whatever branch is current).

> ```
> if [[ ! -z "$changes" ]]; then
>     echo "You may not have the latest ..."
>     echo ""
> fi
> ```

Since you are just going to test whether there are any revisions "ahead of" the current branch on its now-fetched upstream, you don't need a full `git log`.  You can just count these revisions:

```
n=$(git rev-list --count HEAD..@{upstream}) || exit
if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then ...; fi
```

and now you don't even need to find the branch name or its upstream, as `git rev-list --count` will fail automatically:

```
$ git checkout --detach HEAD
HEAD is now at cf11a6797... Eleventh batch for 2.13
$ git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}
fatal: HEAD does not point to a branch
$ git checkout diff-merge-base
Switched to branch 'diff-merge-base'
$ git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'diff-merge-base'
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 137 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
$ git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}
137
```

So, we can reduce the whole script to:

```
n=$(git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}) || exit
if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then
    echo ...
fi
```

I'd avoid recommending `git pull` at all, though.  Now that `git fetch` has fetched, just run `git merge` to get up to date.

Comment: Wow, this was very thorough and helpful. I realized that it doesn't actually matter what account does the pull and push so I'm going to go with using ssh keys since what matters is who commits. 

I'm definitely going to implement your suggestions, thanks!